# Weird char on a 20X4 LCD

Tags: lcd

I'm trying to make an RC controller.

I have a problem with my LCD.

[image: Lcd with japanese and indescribable char like]

I have already double-checked the wiring and the connections are great.

I made a PCB with Kicad and order it to JLCPCB. I have some mistake, you can see the soldered wire.

[image: PCB designed with kicad and made by JLCPCB]

[image: Schema Kicad]

Before the PCB, I did my project with a breadboard and it worked fine.

```cpp
const String menuElem[4] = {"Models", "Trims", "Reverse command", "Channel"};

const int rs = 3, en = 4, d4 = 5, d5 = 6, d6 = 7, d7 = 8;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void menu() {
  lcd.clear();
  //lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  //byte pos = 0;
  //int sizeOfanArray = *(&array + 1) - array;
  byte menuElemLength = *(&menuElem + 1) - menuElem;
  for (byte i = 0; i < menuElemLength; i++) {
    lcd.setCursor(2, i);
    lcd.println(menuElem[i]);
  }
  showMenuNav(currentMenuPos);
}
```

Comment: try `const char* menuElem[4] = {"Models", "Trims", "Reverse command", "Channel"};`

Comment: The pictures of your custom board and wiring job don't really tell us anything. It looks to me like you have a bug in your code. You're getting SOME characters from your strings, which tells me that the LCD is working. It looks to me like your strings are being sent with the wrong lengths.

Comment: Thank you @Juraj it solves the problem. I understand my mistake. I replaced String by char* in my code and in every class. I use `strcat` to concatenate my char* but I don't know if this is the best solution.

@DuncanC Yes, at start i believed that I have bad connection or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to calculate the length of your `String`s does not make sense. The `String` type is an object type. The addresses of your String objects will not match the length of the charcters in those strings. You should use an array of C strings as suggested by Juraj, and then you should use `strlen()` to get the length of those strings (C strings have a null terminating byte, and `strlen()` uses that null to calculate the length. Note that C strings can't handle Unicode.)

The String type is best avoided on Arduino anyway, as String objects tend to fragment the extremely limited heap memory on Arduino devices and cause out-of-memory crashes.

Comment: Yes, my mistake is to use a String object like a `char*` pointer.
I would use ``char*` pointer instead of `String` object in my future code.
Thank you for your reply!